# Undefined reference with Phonon::VideoPlayer

Tags: qt, ubuntu, phonon

I am using ubuntu 11.10 and creating a GUI using QT that uses a cmakelist when building.
The problem I am having is i get the "undefined reference to`Phonon::VideoPlayer::VideoPlayer(Phonon::Category, QWidget*)'" error when running make.

I am using QT 4.7.4 and this "Qt PHONON library not found." also appears when running make.

This is from the cMakeCache

//Path to a library.
QT_PHONONWIDGETS_PLUGIN_RELEASE:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/designer/libphononwidgets.so

//Path to a file.
QT_PHONON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/qt4/phonon

//The Qt PHONON library
QT_PHONON_LIBRARY:STRING=

The string always remains empty.

In my header file this is the related code

include "phonon/VideoPlayer"

Phonon::VideoPlayer* player;

and in the cpp

player = new Phonon::VideoPlayer(Phonon::VideoCategory,this);

any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Jacob

Comment: did you compile from source? In this case did you use the option `--phonon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to copy the four libphonon.so files from QtSDK/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator to usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu to make it work.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. From the ubuntu software center install phonon and libphonon-dev.
2. After that add this to your project file (.pro) ->  QT += phonon
3. Use these header files:

   ```
   #include <phonon/AudioOutput>
   #include <phonon/MediaObject>
   #include <phonon/MediaSource>
   #include <phonon/VideoWidget>
   #include <phonon/VideoPlayer>


   using namespace Phonon;
   ```

And this is a simple example from the Qt's documentation:

```
 VideoPlayer *player = new VideoPlayer(Phonon::VideoCategory, parentWidget);
 connect(player, SIGNAL(finished()), player, SLOT(deleteLater()));
 player->play(url);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. To UmNyobe im just using make and that does everything.To Milen , Im not using a .pro file rather just using QT libraries. If I omit the Phonon:: before the VideoPlayer it complains thats it is not a type. I tried to use phonon in a mock project that has a .pro file and it worked fine after adding QT += phonon so for some reason it seems cmake cannot find QT phonon libraries. I have added (QT_USE_PHONON TRUE) but this has made no difference. Thanks again for helping me. Any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux install phonon and libphonon-dev: 
$sudo apt-get install phonon libphonon-dev

After you can include in your project.pro file:

LIBS += -lphonon

If doesn't works, you can certificate if the lib is installed: 
$locate libphonon.so

The output maybe is: "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libphonon.so"

you can include in your project.pro file:
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu

LIBS += -lphonon